# Setup Installation for Desktop application in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have an issues about setup related :

How to avoid same setup file installing  repetitively then it give an exception like already installed you to remove or repair exception so I want installation work continuously no any give exception. When I am re trying installation then it cannot give us exception, so how to do? In visual studio installer.

Comment: Clearly the Visual Studio Installer does not have a fundamental bug that makes it repeatedly rewrite the same file over and over. You have to be doing something wrong, but we can't tell because you don't show us a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

If you use Wix to help create your MSI, it automatically cannot be installed more than once without rebuilding the installer.